# How to call a method from a different recipe?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am trying to access a method in recipe 'B' of cookbook "b" from recipe 'A' of cookbook "a". I have included the recipe 'B' in recipe 'A' using include_recipe 'cookbook::recipe'.

```
    #cookbook Flower
    #chef recipe 'Rose' DSL
     def method_to_be_called 
        do something
     end

    #cookbook Animal
    #chef recipe 'Tiger' DSL
    include_recipe "Flower::Rose"
      #call method_to_be_called of 'Rose' recipe
   end
```

I am learning Ruby and Chef DSL, hence I don't know what I'm trying to achieve is possible or not. If yes, how do I call the method?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. it's really hard to figure out what you're trying to do from just a verbal description of your code. Instead, can you please edit your question and add the relevant section of code into it? (don't just reply in comments, cos the code formatting is awful)

Comment: You should not be defining methods in recipes. For that libraries are provided. https://docs.chef.io/libraries.html

Comment: Thanks. May I know the reason why it is not recommended to not define methods in a recipe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That isn't really how Chef works. You can wrap your method in a library and call it that way.

For example, put your method in:

```
# cookbook/rose/libraries/helper.rb
class Rose
   def self.method_to_be_called
   end
end

# cookbook/tiger/recipes/default.rb
Rose.method_to_be_called()
```

Comment: Okay. thanks! Is it possible to call a node attribute inside that method which will be in library?

Comment: This works without any issues, thanks a lot!